# Android Empty Screen

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity

I made a code just to learn some android coding. The project is just a true false "game"
.But I debugged it and i get empty screen and nothing more..I debugged it on real phone galaxy note II
Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your layout. issue with the relative layout background. Your setting the string as background

```
android:background="@string/add"
```

change it to set to some drawable/color

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout should get proper background. String is not a valid value for background.
Try removing

```
android:background="@string/add"
```